# Initial value for every array type

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following question. When creating a new array, then there can be inserted initially values. for example `int array[12];` It will create an array of 12 values with initial value. For example for int array it would be array of 0's. 
I have created this array as a part of template class object.
And every time I am changing this array type to `int`, `char`, `float`, `string` or `double`.
What if I have changed some of the values in the any of this type of the array for example to 5 for `int`, `float`, and `double`. To 'c' for char. And to "string" for strings. How can I use the same code for all this objects to set them all to the initial value?

I tried to make:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeOf(T)*13);
```

or

```
memset(array, '\0', sizeOf(T)*13);
```

or

```
memset(array, NULL, sizeOf(T)*13);
```

or

```
memset(array, "", sizeOf(T)*13);
```

But in all these cases it does not work for any of the types. Could anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill_n(array, length, T());
```

(Edited to include Benjamin Lindley's suggestion.)

Comment: I am asking more about the value, than for the method that to use. It works for memset or for fill_n perfectly. But I need the value, which could be set for any data type. Initial value. for example fill_n(array, length, 0);
But the problem is that it will not work for strings array. So I need a value which will work for any these data types (int, float, string, double, char).

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence of bytes that is simultaneously an int, float, string, double, and char? If so, you will not find it.

Comment: Yes, Paul, I am looking for that. Thank you for help!

Comment: @armprognew: If this is in a template, and you just want to use the default value, then you can pass `T()`.  And by the way, no, `memset` absolutely will not work correctly for anything other than POD types.  And it won't work with non-zero values for anything greater than 1 byte (i.e. -- `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`).

Comment: Thank you very much, can you show me please a small example of passing T()? I am not sure I am correctly understanding that do you mean.

Comment: @armprognew: `std::fill_n(array, length, T());`